# general database modeling and django specific modeling

Tags: django-models, database-design

I'm wondering what is the best way to model something like the following.

Lets say my company sells metal bars (parameters/fields are: length, profile_type, quantity etc.) of different profiles, where profiles may be pipe(pipe_diameter, wall_thickness) or hollow_rectangle(base, height, wall_thickness), or maybe some other profile with different parameters. Lets say maximum number of profiles would be 12, each profile having between 2-5 parameters.

Should everything be in a single table like
table_bars: id, length, quantity, profile_type, pipe_diameter, wall_thickness, base, height, etc.) where profile type would be (pipe, rectangle etc.)

or should every shape have its own table with its own parameters and in table_bars keep only id, length, quantity profile_type and profile_id)

and are there any django specific issues is multiple tables are the best answer?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic issue and comes down to your own judgment.  I had a case like this many years ago and went for *generalizing* the parameters, in one table.  Then I made a second table that contained descriptions for the parameters based on the profile, and flags for which were required, optional, or ignored.

You various parameters might be:

Lentgh: Universal for all, no?

WidthOuter1: might be height of square or rectangle, radius of pipe, etc.

WidthOuter2: ignored for pipe and square, required for rectangle

WidthInner1: ignored for solid objects, required for hollow.  Treated just like WidthOuter1, ie., radius for pipes, dimension of square, first dimension for rectangles

WidthInner2: same ideas as WidthOther2 and Widthinner1

...And perhaps your other properties would yield to the same treatment.

Comment: Wow, I forgot about this.  Glad it helped :)